# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - T-SQL language - 'Gaps & Islands' problem - tricky partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partition, gaps-and-islands, row-number

I have 5 employees with ID values : 111, 222, 333, 444, 555.

I have a source dataset that has data for all five of them on all calendar days between Mar 28, 2021 and Apr 5, 2021. (This is just a small sample subset of my actual data).

You can use these scripts to see the sample of the source data:

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceDataset
(
    EmployeeId int,
    PayGroupName varchar(100),
    PayTypeName varchar(100),
    SiteName varchar(100),
    Region varchar(100),
    PercentageScore int,
    Center int,
    [Function] varchar(100),
    Department varchar(100),
    EverySingleCalendarDate date
)

--- for Employee ID = 111 ---

INSERT INTO #SourceDataset
VALUES (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 100, 17, 'WQ', 'FG', '3/28/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 100, 17, 'WQ', 'FG', '3/29/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 100, 17, 'WQ', 'FG', '3/30/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 100, 17, 'WQ', 'FG', '3/31/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 100, 17, 'WQ', 'FG', '4/1/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 50, 56, 'WQ', 'FG', '4/2/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 50, 80, 'WQ', 'FG', '4/2/2021'),
       (111, 'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor', 'NYC', 50, 56, 'WQ', 'FG', '4/3/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',   'NYC',  50, 80, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/3/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',   'NYC',  50, 56, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',   'NYC',  50, 80, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',   'NYC',  50, 56, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/5/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly', 'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',   'NYC',  50, 80, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/5/2021')

--- for Employee ID = 111 ---

--- for Employee ID = 222 ---

INSERT INTO #SourceDataset

VALUES

(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    20, 'WR',   'FY',   '3/31/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    20, 'WR',   'FY',   '4/1/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  25, 19, 'RH',   'FG',   '4/2/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  75, 19, 'DP',   'FG',   '4/2/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  25, 19, 'RH',   'FG',   '4/3/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  75, 19, 'DP',   'FG',   '4/3/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',  'PartTime', 'Office Room',  'POR',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/5/2021')

--- for Employee ID = 222 ---

--- for Employee ID = 333 ---

INSERT INTO #SourceDataset

VALUES

(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly PT', 'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly PT', 'Temporary', 'Store',    'ATL',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/31/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/1/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  40, 19, 'WQ',   'PQ',   '4/2/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  60, 19, 'WQ',   'AD',   '4/2/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  40, 19, 'WQ',   'PQ',   '4/3/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  60, 19, 'WQ',   'AD',   '4/3/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  40, 19, 'WQ',   'PQ',   '4/4/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  60, 19, 'WQ',   'AD',   '4/4/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  40, 19, 'WQ',   'PQ',   '4/5/2021'),
(333, 'Weekly',    'Contract',  'Store',    'ATL',  60, 19, 'WQ',   'AD',   '4/5/2021')

--- for Employee ID = 333 ---

--- for Employee ID = 444 ---

INSERT INTO #SourceDataset

VALUES

(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT-Optional',  'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT-Optional',  'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/31/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/1/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 10, 'AB',   'FG',   '4/2/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 11, 'HP',   'FG',   '4/2/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 10, 'AB',   'FG',   '4/3/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 11, 'HP',   'FG',   '4/3/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  65, 29, 'RR',   'FG',   '4/4/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  35, 37, 'QQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 10, 'AB',   'FG',   '4/5/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',   'FT',           'StoreHouse',   'MIA',  50, 11, 'HP',   'FG',   '4/5/2021')

--- for Employee ID = 444 ---

--- for Employee ID = 555 ---

INSERT INTO #SourceDataset

VALUES

(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021'),
(555,   'WeeklyOptional',           'PT',   'StoreHouse2',    'RIC',    100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/31/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/1/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    40, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/2/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    25, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/2/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    35, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/2/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    40, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    25, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    35, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',           'FT',   'StoreHouse156',  'RIC',    33, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',           'FT',   'StoreHouse156',  'RIC',    33, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',           'FT',   'StoreHouse156',  'RIC',    34, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    40, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/5/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    25, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/5/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',                   'FT',   'StoreHouse1',    'RIC',    35, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/5/2021')

--- for Employee ID = 555 ---

SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
ORDER BY EmployeeId, EverySingleCalendarDate

---------------------------------------------------
```

Goal: I am trying to track how an employee attained 100 % Percentage Score over a period of time, and develop groups to display this information, with a new **MinDate** and **MaxDate** column, to show the range of dates for which a group existed. There is no gap in the calendar days for any employee, in the time period mentioned here (Mar 28, 2021 - Apr 5, 2021).

A note on the source dataset:

An employee may attain 100 % Percentage Score in one row for a given calendar day, with one unique value each, under each column - Center, Function, Department. Alternately she may attain 100 % Percentage Score on another calendar day, with different combinations of these 3 columns - Center, Function, Department -  in multiple rows, with splits in Percentage
Scores (say, 40 + 25 + 35 in three rows (or) 50 + 50 in two rows), which will add up to 100 %  for that calendar day. See example queries on the source dataset to get an idea as to what I mean.

The source dataset has been developed in such a way that - every calendar day must account for 100 % for any employee, and there is NO gap in the calendar days. And for an employee, the change for these 4 columns (PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region) happen only at the calendar day level,  NOT at the level of PercentageScore column or at the level of Center, Function, Department columns.

```
Example:

SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
WHERE EmployeeId = 111
AND EverySingleCalendarDate = '2021-03-28'
--100 % Percentage Score in one row--

SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
WHERE EmployeeId = 111
AND EverySingleCalendarDate = '2021-04-02'
--100 % Percentage Score in two rows (50 + 50)--

SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
WHERE EmployeeId = 555
AND EverySingleCalendarDate = '2021-04-02'
--100 % Percentage Score in three rows (40 + 25 + 35)--
```

My goal is to track every employee on how she attains 100 % Percentage Score over a period of time - from Mar 28 to Apr 5, with data available for ALL my 5 employees on ALL these days, with no gap in the calendar days in the source dataset.

The number of rows for an employee on a given calendar day, will depend on how she attains 100 % Percentage Score, either in one row
or multiple rows. The 'number of rows' (on a calendar day for any employee) will essentially depend on the set of 3 columns - Center, Function, Department.

Another important point: the columns - PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region - will ALWAYS have exactly one unique value for an employee on a given calendar day. So the number of rows for an employee on a given calendar is NOT determined by these columns -  PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region.

This said, the data under each of these columns (PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region) can change between calendar days for an employee, and we need to track this too. See example queries on the source dataset below:

```
SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
WHERE EmployeeId = 333
AND EverySingleCalendarDate BETWEEN '2021-03-28' AND '2021-03-30'
--PayGroupName and PayTypeName change between days for this employee (333)--

SELECT *
FROM #SourceDataset
WHERE EmployeeId = 555
AND EverySingleCalendarDate BETWEEN '2021-04-03' AND '2021-04-04'
/*
PayGroupName and SiteName change between days for this employee (555);
and its' very important to to note that for an employee, the change for these 4 columns
(PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region) can happen only at the calendar day level, NOT at the
level of Percentage Score or at the level of the columns - Center, Function, Department.

In essence, the change for these 4 columns (PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, Region) for an
employee can happen ONLY at the level of a calendar day.
*/
```

A few weeks back, I posted a question on this same [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918924/microsoft-sql-server-2016-t-sql-obtain-date-range-for-a-dataset-based-on-indi), but the data set was easier, with exactly one row for an employee on any given calendar day.

Today, I have a similar but a challenging situation, in which there can be multiple rows for an employee on a given calendar day. This is based on how an employee (say Employee ID = 111) attains
100 % Percentage Score, for a calendar day, say Mar 28, 2021.

I have the desired output dataset, both as a temp table using T-SQL and as a tabular output, so that you can get an absolute clear picture of the problem I have at hand.

**Desired Output:**

```
CREATE TABLE #DesiredOutput

(

EmployeeId int,
PayGroupName varchar(100),
PayTypeName varchar(100),
SiteName varchar(100),
Region varchar(100),
PercentageScore int,
Center int,
[Function] varchar(100),
Department varchar(100),
MinDate date,
MaxDate date

)


INSERT INTO #DesiredOutput

VALUES


(111,   'Biweekly',         'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',    'NYC', 100,    17, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021',    '4/1/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly',         'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',    'NYC', 50, 56, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(111,   'Biweekly',         'Salaried', 'Shop Floor',    'NYC', 50, 80, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',              'PartTime', 'Office Room',   'POR', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021',    '3/30/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',          'PartTime', 'Office Room',   'POR', 100,    20, 'WR',   'FY',   '3/31/2021',    '4/1/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',          'PartTime', 'Office Room',   'POR', 25, 19, 'RH',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',              'PartTime', 'Office Room',   'POR', 75, 19, 'DP',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(222,   'Monthly',          'PartTime', 'Office Room',   'POR', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly',           'Contract', 'Store',     'ATL', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021',    '3/28/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly PT',            'Contract', 'Store',     'ATL', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021',    '3/29/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly PT',            'Temporary',    'Store',         'ATL', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021',    '3/30/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly',           'Contract', 'Store',         'ATL', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/31/2021',    '4/1/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly',           'Contract', 'Store',     'ATL', 40, 19, 'WQ',   'PQ',   '4/2/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(333,   'Weekly',           'Contract', 'Store',     'ATL', 60, 19, 'WQ',   'AD',   '4/2/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021',    '3/28/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT-Optional',  'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021',    '3/30/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/31/2021',    '4/1/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 50, 10, 'AB',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 50, 11, 'HP',   'FG',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 65, 29, 'RR',   'FG',   '4/4/2021', '4/4/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 35, 37, 'QQ',   'FG',   '4/4/2021', '4/4/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 50, 10, 'AB',   'FG',   '4/5/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(444,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse',    'MIA', 50, 11, 'HP',   'FG',   '4/5/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/28/2021',    '3/28/2021'),
(555,   'WeeklyOptional',   'PT',           'StoreHouse2',   'RIC', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/29/2021',    '3/29/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 100,    19, 'WQ',   'FG',   '3/30/2021',    '4/1/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 40, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 25, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 35, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/2/2021', '4/3/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',   'FT',           'StoreHouse156', 'RIC', 33, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/4/2021', '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',   'FT',           'StoreHouse156', 'RIC', 33, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/4/2021', '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly-NonOptional',   'FT',           'StoreHouse156', 'RIC', 34, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/4/2021', '4/4/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 40, 23, 'BB',   'MA',   '4/5/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 25, 24, 'CV',   'RU',   '4/5/2021', '4/5/2021'),
(555,   'Weekly',           'FT',           'StoreHouse1',   'RIC', 35, 25, 'FJ',   'BN',   '4/5/2021', '4/5/2021')



SELECT *
FROM #DesiredOutput
ORDER BY EmployeeId, MinDate
```

**I need to use #SourceDataset and convert it to #DesiredOutput.**

I need some advice.

For example, the #DesiredOutput (in tabular form) looks as below for an employee (111), and for all employees:

| EmployeeId | PayGroupName | PayTypeName | SiteName | Region | PercentageScore | Center | Function | Department | MinDate | MaxDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 100 | 17 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 50 | 56 | WQ | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 50 | 80 | WQ | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |

| EmployeeId | PayGroupName | PayTypeName | SiteName | Region | PercentageScore | Center | Function | Department | MinDate | MaxDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 100 | 17 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 50 | 56 | WQ | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 111 | Biweekly | Salaried | Shop Floor | NYC | 50 | 80 | WQ | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 222 | Monthly | PartTime | Office Room | POR | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 3/30/2021 |
| 222 | Monthly | PartTime | Office Room | POR | 100 | 20 | WR | FY | 3/31/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 222 | Monthly | PartTime | Office Room | POR | 25 | 19 | RH | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 222 | Monthly | PartTime | Office Room | POR | 75 | 19 | DP | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 222 | Monthly | PartTime | Office Room | POR | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 4/4/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 333 | Weekly | Contract | Store | ATL | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 3/28/2021 |
| 333 | WeeklyPT | Contract | Store | ATL | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/29/2021 | 3/29/2021 |
| 333 | WeeklyPT | Temporary | Store | ATL | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/30/2021 | 3/30/2021 |
| 333 | Weekly | Contract | Store | ATL | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/31/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 333 | Weekly | Contract | Store | ATL | 40 | 19 | WQ | PQ | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 333 | Weekly | Contract | Store | ATL | 60 | 19 | WQ | AD | 4/2/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 3/28/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT-Optional | StoreHouse | MIA | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/29/2021 | 3/30/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/31/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 50 | 10 | AB | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 50 | 11 | HP | FG | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 65 | 29 | RR | FG | 4/4/2021 | 4/4/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 35 | 37 | QQ | FG | 4/4/2021 | 4/4/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 50 | 10 | AB | FG | 4/5/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 444 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse | MIA | 50 | 11 | HP | FG | 4/5/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/28/2021 | 3/28/2021 |
| 555 | WeeklyOptional | PT | StoreHouse2 | RIC | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/29/2021 | 3/29/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 100 | 19 | WQ | FG | 3/30/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 40 | 23 | BB | MA | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 25 | 24 | CV | RU | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 35 | 25 | FJ | BN | 4/2/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly-NonOPTional | FT | StoreHouse156 | RIC | 33 | 23 | BB | MA | 4/4/2021 | 4/4/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly-NonOPTional | FT | StoreHouse156 | RIC | 33 | 24 | CV | RU | 4/4/2021 | 4/4/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly-NonOPTional | FT | StoreHouse156 | RIC | 34 | 25 | FJ | BN | 4/4/2021 | 4/4/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 40 | 23 | BB | MA | 4/5/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 25 | 24 | CV | RU | 4/5/2021 | 4/5/2021 |
| 555 | Weekly | FT | StoreHouse1 | RIC | 35 | 25 | FJ | BN | 4/5/2021 | 4/5/2021 |

Any idea on how to develop the desired output?

The table data at the lower end is the full table, which may be difficult to scroll through; so I have a smaller version for Employee ID = 111 at the top, and the entire desired output next. Alternately, you can use the **T-SQL scripts** to get an idea of the #DesiredOutput dataset.

Comment: Given the length of your question (which is longer than I have time to read), I have to ask the question, is this a [mre] i.e. is this the simplest form of the problem you can come up with?

Comment: @Dale K     this is a fairly complex one, so i feel image files are necessary to describe

Comment: @Dale K     I have removed the image files. Can you now allow the question?

Comment: @Dale K: I have removed some parts of the question, now the length is significantly reduced

Comment: how to open it again ?

Comment: If it makes sense to people they will vote to re open it.

Comment: what would be your comment ? would you mind voting for re-opening ? or do you still want me to change something?

Comment: Would have been helpful to see what result you were looking for.

Comment: @JMabee    i have added some extra codes with the desired output (previously they were image files, but i was advised me to remove images)

Comment: @Dale K   how to put tablular data into the quetion?

Comment: It's still way too unclear and verbose. Please pay attention to the *minimal* part of [mcve], we need all the info that explains the problem, and nothing else. Eg you can remove those "static" columns that are not relevant to the question. Tables: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: @Charlieface    ok am reviewing it to make it concise

Comment: @Charlieface    I have posted a table finally; would it be okay for you to vote to re-open?

Comment: @Dale K   I have posted a table finally;  thanks

Comment: No I wouldn't. I still can't get my head around what you want, because there is too much extraneous info here for me to absorb. You need to cut back to a more minimal question, and sort out formatting/paragraphing

Comment: OP's problem would be minimal like this: There is a table with columns [key], [data], and [date]. They want to convert it to a table with [key],[data],[mindate],[maxdate] which groups consecutive days with the same (key,data). I expect there are similar questions around.

Comment: The answer is hidden in tip #5 of this site: https://blog.jooq.org/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/. I don't have DB access to post an answer atm.

Comment: @Charlieface   this is similar to the solution you provided me last time with the LAG function. Is there any hint you can provide me ? Or do you want me to clarify something with the question ? Please let me know.

Comment: @Павел Сивоплясов    is there any advice you can provide, on how to develop the PARTITION BY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used:

- Calculating a flag to indicate gaps of more than 1 day.
- Creating a ranking based on summing the flag.
- Group it up, including the calculated ranking.

```
SELECT EmployeeId, PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, 
Region, PercentageScore,Center, [Function], Department
, MIN(EverySingleCalendarDate) MinDate
, MAX(EverySingleCalendarDate) MaxDate
INTO #tmpResults
FROM (
  SELECT *
  , Rnk = SUM(Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, 
Region, PercentageScore,Center, [Function], Department ORDER BY EverySingleCalendarDate)
  FROM
  (
     SELECT *
     , Flag = IIF(1=DATEDIFF(day, LAG(EverySingleCalendarDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, 
Region, PercentageScore,Center, [Function], Department ORDER BY EverySingleCalendarDate), EverySingleCalendarDate),0,1)
     FROM #SourceDataset
  ) q1
) q2
GROUP BY EmployeeId, PayGroupName, PayTypeName, SiteName, 
Region, PercentageScore,Center, [Function], Department, Rnk
ORDER BY EmployeeId, MinDate;

SELECT * FROM #tmpResults;
```

> ```
> --
> -- Differences
> --
> SELECT * FROM #tmpResults
> EXCEPT
> SELECT * FROM #DesiredOutput;
>
> SELECT * FROM #DesiredOutput
> EXCEPT
> SELECT * FROM #tmpResults;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EmployeeId | PayGroupName | PayTypeName | SiteName | Region | PercentageScore | Center | Function | Department | MinDate | MaxDate
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------- | :------- | :----- | --------------: | -----: | :------- | :--------- | :------ | :------
>
> EmployeeId | PayGroupName | PayTypeName | SiteName | Region | PercentageScore | Center | Function | Department | MinDate | MaxDate
> ---------: | :----------- | :---------- | :------- | :----- | --------------: | -----: | :------- | :--------- | :------ | :------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf298b2acf91c8671f9038707923de32)*

Comment: thanks very much; appreciate your help; am working on your solution; I'll get back

Comment: am planning going to test this query with my full dataset later this week; hopefully, after that I will mark your answer ; thanks very much.

Comment: thanks very much, you solution has worked perfectly on the actual data I have for 2020 and 2021. I will test further with more historical data, in the next few days, and hopefully there should be no issue. Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what @LukStorms provided, but formatted better so that anyone can use this code. Thanks very much for your support.

```
SELECT

k.EmployeeId,k.PayGroupName,k.PayTypeName,k.SiteName,k.Region,k.PercentageScore,k.Center,k.[Function],k.Department,

MIN(k.EverySingleCalendarDate) AS MinDate,
MAX(k.EverySingleCalendarDate) AS MaxDate

FROM

(

SELECT

g.*,

SUM(g.Flag) OVER

(

PARTITION BY

g.EmployeeId,g.PayGroupName,g.PayTypeName,g.SiteName,g.Region,g.PercentageScore,g.Center,g.[Function],g.Department

ORDER BY g.EverySingleCalendarDate

) AS Rnk

FROM
 
(

SELECT

*,

Flag = CASE

           WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,

                          LAG(EverySingleCalendarDate,1) OVER

                          (PARTITION BY

                          EmployeeId,PayGroupName,PayTypeName,SiteName,Region,PercentageScore,Center,[Function],Department

                          ORDER BY EverySingleCalendarDate),

                          EverySingleCalendarDate) = 1 THEN 0

            ELSE 1

        END

FROM 

#SourceDataset

) g

) k

GROUP BY

k.EmployeeId,k.PayGroupName,k.PayTypeName,k.SiteName,k.Region,k.PercentageScore,k.Center,k.[Function],k.Department,
k.Rnk
--note the Rnk column in the GROUP BY
--ORDER BY k.EmployeeId, MinDate
```