# Getting datetime count range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I try to get the date range between the data changes in SQL Server
my query is

```
select count(1) as qty, Info, convert(char,dFError,100) dErr
from TableData
group by Info, convert(char,dFError,100) 
order by dErr asc
```

I have this
qty has the number of reques to a server, info are the servers ip and the date it's when a request it's sended to another server.

| qty | Info | dErr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.97 | Aug 11 2021 9:01AM |
| 1 | 1.97 | Aug 11 2021 9:06AM |
| 88 | 1.33 | Dec 21 2021 2:04PM |
| 1 | 1.95 | Dec 22 2021 9:44PM |
| 9 | 1.95 | Dec 22 2021 9:45PM |
| 1 | 1.33 | Dec 22 2021 9:51PM |
| 19 | 1.33 | Dec 22 2021 9:52PM |
| 3 | 1.33 | Dec 22 2021 9:53PM |
| 6 | 1.33 | Dec 27 2021 7:10PM |
| 17 | 1.33 | Dec 27 2021 7:11PM |
| 15 | 1.95 | Dec 27 2021 7:17PM |
| 8 | 1.95 | Dec 27 2021 7:18PM |

and I want this, in Aug 11 at 9:06AM all are going to 1.97, at Dec 21 at 2:04PM all are going to 1.33, that means the date and the info

| qty | Info | dErr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.97 | Aug 11 2021 9:06AM |
| 88 | 1.33 | Dec 21 2021 2:04PM |
| 10 | 1.95 | Dec 22 2021 9:45PM |
| 46 | 1.33 | Dec 27 2021 7:11PM |
| 23 | 1.95 | Dec 27 2021 7:18PM |

in the same day can be the same group of numbers on distinct hour

| qty | Info | dErr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 9:39AM |
| 1 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 9:51AM |
| 1 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 9:58AM |
| 4 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 10:08AM |
| 1 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 10:12AM |
| 8 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 10:24AM |
| 2 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 10:32AM |
| 10 | 1.33 | Jan 24 2022 10:33AM |
| 1 | 1.33 | Jan 24 2022 11:37AM |
| 8 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 11:59AM |
| 1 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 12:00PM |
| 2 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 12:08PM |

and need to be displayed like

| qty | Info | dErr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1.97 | Jan 24 2022 10:12AM |
| 10 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 10:32AM |
| 11 | 1.33 | Jan 24 2022 11:37AM |
| 11 | 1.95 | Jan 24 2022 12:08PM |

Comment: Have you looked at `sum` , `max` and `group by`?

Comment: Please edit your question showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: The query you provided uses columns not seen elsewhere in your "I want this". Please provide a query and data that relates to it, as well as a question and DDL.

Comment: Yea, I tried with sum, max, group by, but I can't get what I need, I add more information, and make corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double row_number can be used to calculate a ranking.
Then the ranking can be used in the aggregation to solve this Gaps-And-Islands type of problem.

> ```
> select sum(qty) as qty, Info, max(dFError) as dErr
> from (
>   select Info, dFError, qty
>   , convert(date, dFError) as dErrorDate
>   , Rnk = row_number() over (order by dFError)
>   + row_number() over (partition by Info order by dFError desc)
>   from TableData
> ) q
> group by Info, Rnk
> order by dErr;
> ```

> | qty | Info | dErr |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 1.97 | 2021-08-11 09:06:00.000 |
> | 88 | 1.33 | 2021-12-21 14:04:00.000 |
> | 10 | 1.95 | 2021-12-22 21:45:00.000 |
> | 46 | 1.33 | 2021-12-27 19:11:00.000 |
> | 23 | 1.95 | 2021-12-27 19:18:00.000 |
> | 8 | 1.97 | 2022-01-24 10:12:00.000 |
> | 10 | 1.95 | 2022-01-24 10:32:00.000 |
> | 11 | 1.33 | 2022-01-24 11:37:00.000 |
> | 11 | 1.95 | 2022-01-24 12:08:00.000 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=afefc5ab9f8badea5cd2b09a42115c58)*

Comment: great!! that is, I'm not good with row_number I'll try to read more about that

Comment: There are more useful window functions like that. And [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70162999/4003419) of an alternative method to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    SUM(P_COUNT) as "COUNT", 
    P_DATA as "DATA", 
    MAX(FECHA) as "FECHA"
from 
    TABLEA
GROUP BY 
    P_DATA, CONVERT(DATE, FECHA)
ORDER BY "FECHA"
```

Comment: This only give me the last date, but sometimes the values ​​are intertwined, like    > 8 1.95  Jan 24 2022 10:24AM           
>2 1.95      Jan 24 2022 10:32AM           
>10 1.33    Jan 24 2022 10:33AM           
>1 1.33    Jan 24 2022 11:37AM           
>8 1.95    Jan 24 2022 11:59AM           
>1 1.95    Jan 24 2022 12:00PM

Answer (score 0):

Your expected results don't match the given data - in the first set you have rows for 12/22 with both 1.33 and 1.95, but not included in your expected results.

It seems to me you want to either group by the date - or the date\hour.  Here is an example of both:

```
Declare @testTable table (qty int, Info numeric(3,2), dErr datetime);
 Insert Into @testTable (qty, Info, dErr)
 Values ( 1, 1.97, 'Aug 11 2021 9:01AM')
      , ( 1, 1.97, 'Aug 11 2021 9:06AM')
      , (88, 1.33, 'Dec 21 2021 2:04PM')
      , ( 1, 1.95, 'Dec 22 2021 9:44PM')
      , ( 9, 1.95, 'Dec 22 2021 9:45PM')
      , ( 1, 1.33, 'Dec 22 2021 9:51PM')
      , (19, 1.33, 'Dec 22 2021 9:52PM')
      , ( 3, 1.33, 'Dec 22 2021 9:53PM')
      , ( 6, 1.33, 'Dec 27 2021 7:10PM')
      , (17, 1.33, 'Dec 27 2021 7:11PM')
      , (15, 1.95, 'Dec 27 2021 7:17PM')
      , ( 8, 1.95, 'Dec 27 2021 7:18PM')

      , ( 1, 1.97, 'Jan 24 2022 9:39AM')
      , ( 1, 1.97, 'Jan 24 2022 9:51AM')
      , ( 1, 1.97, 'Jan 24 2022 9:58AM')
      , ( 4, 1.97, 'Jan 24 2022 10:08AM')
      , ( 1, 1.97, 'Jan 24 2022 10:12AM')
      , ( 8, 1.95, 'Jan 24 2022 10:24AM')
      , ( 2, 1.95, 'Jan 24 2022 10:32AM')
      , (10, 1.33, 'Jan 24 2022 10:33AM')
      , ( 1, 1.33, 'Jan 24 2022 11:37AM')
      , ( 8, 1.95, 'Jan 24 2022 11:59AM')
      , ( 1, 1.95, 'Jan 24 2022 12:00PM')
      , ( 2, 1.95, 'Jan 24 2022 12:08PM');

 --==== Grouped by date
 Select total_qty = sum(tt.qty)
      , tt.Info
      , latest_date = max(tt.dErr)
   From @testTable tt
  Group By
        tt.Info
      , cast(tt.dErr As date)
  Order By
        cast(tt.dErr As date);

 --==== Grouped by date\hour
 Select total_qty = sum(tt.qty)
      , tt.Info
      , latest_date = max(tt.dErr)
   From @testTable tt
  Group By
        tt.Info
      , cast(tt.dErr As date)
      , datepart(Hour, tt.dErr)
  Order By
        cast(tt.dErr As date)
      , datepart(Hour, tt.dErr);
```

Comment: The numbers, 1.95, 1.97, 1.33 are 3 servers, the request are sended "randomly" to each one, the date are when the request it's sended to another server, I'm counting the numer of request to each server until it changes and have the interval of the time where it changed